# Sending messages in FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on Firebase with a chat feature, and now I am able to connect to FCM(did as guided in google developers console). But I didn't understand how to send and receive messages between two devices.

An FCM implementation includes an app server that interacts with FCM via HTTP or XMPP protocol, and a client app.

How can I communicate through FCM? How do we send messages? I did something like this and it does nothing

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] sendMessage:payloadDict to:recevierID withMessageID:identity timeToLive:10];
```

Need help how to send messages and receive. Thanks In Advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you begin, you need a few things set up in your environment:

- Xcode 7.0 or later.
- For Cloud Messaging:

  1. A physical iOS device.
  2. APNs certificate with Push Notifications enabled.
- An Xcode project and its bundle identifier.
- CocoaPods 1.0.0 or later.

.Once you are done with the [setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message) you can go on and send a message

**Sending a message**

1. Install and run the app on the target device. You'll need to accept
   the request for permission to receive remote notifications.
2. Make sure the app is in the background on the device.
3. Open the Notifications tab of the Firebase console and select New
   Message.
4. Enter the message text.
5. Select Single Device for the message target.
6. In the field labeled FCM Registration Token, enter the registration
   token you obtained in a previous section of this guide.

Check the [Receive Messages in an iOS App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) for receiving message

Firebase Cloud Messaging provides two ways to target a message to multiple devices:

1. [Topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group), which allows you to send a message to multiple
   devices that have opted in to a particular topic.
2. [Device group messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group), which allows you to send a message to
   multiple devices that belong to a group you define.

an ex:-

First connect to FCM

```
-(void)connectToFcm {
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
  }];
}
```

send a message

```
[[FIRMessaging message]sendMessage:message
                                to:receiver
                     withMessageID:messageID
                        timeToLive:ttl;
```

When your app goes into the background, disconnect from FCM

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
  NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
```

Comment: Hi Tony as u mentioned the list of things  i did all its working perfectly when i send message from notification Tab from google console am able to recevie notification on my device and now how do i send message to other device here i got stuck actaually! how should we send message from App to other device

Comment: With device group messaging, app servers can send a single message to multiple instances of an app running on devices belonging to a group. Obtain registration tokens for each device and Create the `notification_key`. See my edit

Comment: so communication between two devices through firebase is with notifications  only ??? [[FIRMessaging messaging]  how does this class work .. and  how should i send message from app ! which method i should use in ios !

Comment: [[FIRMessaging message]sendMessage:message
                                to:receiver
                     withMessageID:messageID
                        timeToLive:ttl;  with this method where the message will go ?? directly to other user or it will got to firebase server and then it wil  deliver from there ??? it will go as notification or live message connects to other  user

Comment: it goes to the app server. When FCM receives an upstream messaging call from a client app, it generates an XMPP stanza for sending the upstream message

Comment: and also do we need to  implement any thing related to XMPP for sending and receiving messages for ios app or fire base will takecare???and am implementing one to one chat when  where should i receive a message from DidreceiveRemoteNotification method or is there any method in fire base(for ios )to accept incoming message